# powershell to list all users mobiledevicestatistics and their title and department

Tags: powershell, active-directory, office365, activesync

I am trying to get a listing of all users with mobile devices using activesync, device model, last sync time AND their department and manager.

I am trying to combine the followin commandlets but can't seem to find a way to get it to work.

Note: We are using O365.

The commandlets I have been using are: Get-Mailbox, Get-MobileDeviceStatistics and Get-ADUser.

Basically, I need a report with:

Name
Title
Manager
Office
Device Type
Device OS
Last Sync Attempt Time

Thanks,

Comment: Current code, where are you stuck? What results are you getting?

Comment: right now all i have is two separate statements:

Comment: Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | ForEach-Object { $PrimarySmtpAddress = $_.PrimarySmtpAddress; Get-MobileDeviceStatistics -Mailbox $_.Identity | Select-Object @{ Name = 'PrimarySmtpAddress'; Expression = { $PrimarySmtpAddress } }, DeviceType, DeviceOS, DeviceMobileOperator, LastSyncAttemptTime }

Comment: Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Select-Object DisplayName, title, office, department, managerG

Comment: Clean it up, and put it in the body of the post.